# How to compare two folder and generate a report using svn

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, diff

Is there any tool in windows to compare two folder and to generate difference report by using "Tortoise SVN". can any one help me to do this.

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While alroc **is totally right** (but his selection of diff-tool is a question, next question), TortoiseSVN (surprise !!!) can be used as tool for diffing folder (it's perversion, yes, but it's possible)

- Create new repo
- Import into repo `Folder I`
- Import into repo `Folder II`
- `svn diff ... > report` two folders in repo and get difference-report
- Delete repo

Comment: thanks Lazy Badger, 
i'm using windows xp, when i give `svn diff Folder I Folder II > report.txt` it will generate only the empty file, even in command prompt also no result. 
can you help me to over come this.

Comment: @Ramesh - your form of diff usable **only** in case of comparing folders inside **Working Copy** (when folders are subdirs of current dir). For comparing folders in **repo**, both folders must be defined as **URLs in repo**

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is the wrong tool for the job if you have two arbitrary folders and need to compare them. It's like using a wrench to pound nails - it works by using a particular feature, but it's not going to get you the results you want.

I use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare both files and folders. Whether it will produce the report output you're looking for I can't say, as you haven't defined what this "report" should show (or now).

Comment: thanks alroc, can WinMerge do a recursive search to find out the differences.

Comment: What kind of differences? Differences in each file, or differences between subdirectories? Either way, the software is *free* and you can find out definitely on your own instead of depending on someone else to interpret your question properly.

Comment: i had tried the winmerge, i think its not going for subdirectories. Also i need differences in each file.

Comment: Start WinMerge. File -> Open. In the Select Files or Folders dialog, check the box that says "Include Subfolders" and it should check everything.